# i try to delete Label but i can't delete & my code a lot of line need somebody to advice

Tags: python, tkinter, tkinter-button, tkinter-text, tkinter-label

I'm writing a Tkinter Application. I'm trying to delete a `Label` by using `destroy()` but it is not working correctly.

What would be the correct way to delete (or remove) the `Label`.

Base code:

```py
typeimport tkinter
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk

window=Tk()
window.minsize(300,200)
window.title("COMBO 3 PIECE 1 SODA")

Label(text="UFC make fight",font=20,pady=10 ,padx=10).grid(row=0,column=0,sticky=W)
opponet=StringVar(value="คู่ต่อสู้ของคุณ")
combo2=ttk.Combobox(textvariable=opponet)
combo2["value"]=("Conor Mcgregor","Jorge Masvidal","Colby Covington","Tony Ferguson","Sean O malley")
combo2.grid(row=0,column=2)

choice = StringVar(value="เลือกนักสู้ของคุณ")
combo=ttk.Combobox(textvariable=choice)
combo["value"]=("Conor Mcgregor","Jorge Masvidal","Colby Covington","Tony Ferguson","Sean O malley")
combo.grid(row=0,column=1)

#betodd2 = IntVar()
#betset2=Entry(font=30,width=10,textvariable=betodd2).grid(row=1,column=2)
Label(text="ประเมินทักษะมวยปล้ำ",font=20,pady=10 ,padx=10).grid(row=1,column=0,sticky=W)
Label(text="ค่าทักษะมวยสากล",font=20,pady=10 ,padx=10).grid(row=2,column=0,sticky=W)
Label(text="ค่าทักษะมวยไทย",font=20,pady=10 ,padx=10).grid(row=3,column=0,sticky=W)
Label(text="ค่าทักษะBJJ",font=20,pady=10 ,padx=10).grid(row=4,column=0,sticky=W)
WrestlingPoint1 = IntVar()
Spinbox(from_=1,to=10,textvariable=WrestlingPoint1).grid(row=1,column=1)
WrestlingPoint2 = IntVar()
Spinbox(from_=1,to=10,textvariable=WrestlingPoint2).grid(row=1,column=2)
BoxingPoint1 = IntVar()
Spinbox(from_=1,to=10,textvariable=BoxingPoint1).grid(row=2,column=1)
BoxingPoint2 = IntVar()
Spinbox(from_=1,to=10,textvariable=BoxingPoint2).grid(row=2,column=2)
MuayThaiPoint1 = IntVar()
Spinbox(from_=1,to=10,textvariable=MuayThaiPoint1).grid(row=3,column=1)
MuayThaiPoint2 = IntVar()
Spinbox(from_=1,to=10,textvariable=MuayThaiPoint2).grid(row=3,column=2)
BJJPoint1 = IntVar()
Spinbox(from_=1,to=10,textvariable=BJJPoint1).grid(row=4,column=1)
BJJPoint2 = IntVar()
Spinbox(from_=1,to=10,textvariable=BJJPoint2).grid(row=4,column=2)

Label(text="รวมผลคะแนน",font=20,pady=10 ,padx=10).grid(row=5,column=0,sticky=W)

Label(text="คะแนนนักสู้คนที่ 1 ",font=20,pady=10 ,padx=10).grid(row=6,column=1)
Label(text="คะแนนนักสู้คนที่ 2 ",font=20,pady=10 ,padx=10).grid(row=6,column=2)

content1=""
content2=""
txt_input= StringVar(value="0")
txt_input2= StringVar(value="0")

TOTAL1=Entry(font=('impact',15,'bold'),fg='black',bg='red',width=10,textvariable=txt_input).grid(row=5, column=1)
TOTAL2=Entry(font=('impact',15,'bold'),fg='black',bg='red',width=10,textvariable=txt_input2).grid(row=5, column=2)

going=Label(window)
going2=Label(window)
#summary=Entry(font=('impact',15,'bold'),fg='black',bg='red',width=10,textvariable=txt_input).grid(row=10, column=0,columnspan=0)
```

The `clearcommand` function:

```py
def clearcommand():
    global content1
    content1 = ""
    global content2
    content2 = ""
    txt_input = StringVar(value="0")
    txt_input2 = StringVar(value="0")
    Label.destroy()
    TOTAL1 = Entry(font=('impact', 15, 'bold'), fg='black', bg='red', width=10, textvariable=txt_input).grid(row=5,
                                                                                                             column=1)
    TOTAL2 = Entry(font=('impact', 15, 'bold'), fg='black', bg='red', width=10, textvariable=txt_input2).grid(row=5,
                                                                                                              column=2)

    confirm['state']=NORMAL

clear=Button(text="เคลียร์ข้อมูล",command=clearcommand,font=30,background='red').grid(row=11,column=2)
```

Comment: I've already edited the post, but you will need to trim down your code even more. Make sure to use clear English, not fill your question with fluff, and provide a minimal reproducible example.

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 1):

None of your `Label` widgets are being stored in variables, so you're not going to be able to modify (or `destroy`) them after the fact.

You should store the `Label` you want to update in a variable, then if you just want to clear out the text of the label without actually destroying the widget, you can modify `clearcommand` like this:

```
my_label = Label(...)  # label to be modified, code omitted for brevity
my_label.grid(...)  # put the label on the grid, code omitted for brevity

# you need to add the label to the grid *separately* from declaring it, otherwise
# 'my_label' will be 'None' instead of a reference to the Label object!

# this is because 'grid()' returns 'None', so if you do 'my_label = Label(...).grid(...)', 
# then 'my_label' will evaluate to 'None', which is not what you want!


def clearcommand():
    global content1
    content1 = ""
    global content2
    content2 = ""
    txt_input = StringVar(value="0")
    txt_input2 = StringVar(value="0")

    # set the label's text to an empty string
    my_label.config(text='')

    TOTAL1 = Entry(font=('impact', 15, 'bold'), fg='black', bg='red', width=10, textvariable=txt_input).grid(row=5,column=1)
    TOTAL2 = Entry(font=('impact', 15, 'bold'), fg='black', bg='red', width=10, textvariable=txt_input2).grid(row=5, column=2)
```

Updating the label this way means that the widget still exists and can be changed again later

Answer (score 0):

> i try to delete Label but i can't delete

- In line 25 - 55, every widget must be assigned to variables.
- Every widget must split into two lines instead of  one line to
  prevent errors.
- In line 25 - 55, every widget must be assigned to variables
- In line 62, 63, 82 and 87, comment out `#content1=""` `and #content1=""`
  So we don't need `global`.
- In line 91 and 92 comment out `#going=Label(window)`
  `#going2=Label(window)`. We don't know what is this doing.
- Comment out all `#global` in functions
- In line 113, 117 and 120, Replace Label with `lbl_x.configure`. x
  denote index

In `clearcommand()`.

- Add `Lbl_x.destroy()` x denote index
- Add `delete` for `Entry`
- Add `IntVar()` to variables for every `Spinbox` and `sbx.configure`.
  the x denote index
- In line 158, `lbl_4 = Label` outside function.

Snippet:

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk

window=Tk()
window.minsize(300,200)
window.title("COMBO 3 PIECE 1 SODA")

Label(text="UFC make fight",font=20,pady=10 ,padx=10).grid(row=0,column=0,sticky=W)
opponet=StringVar(value="คู่ต่อสู้ของคุณ")
combo2=ttk.Combobox(textvariable=opponet)
combo2["value"]=("Conor Mcgregor","Jorge Masvidal","Colby Covington","Tony Ferguson","Sean O malley")
combo2.grid(row=0,column=2)

choice = StringVar(value="เลือกนักสู้ของคุณ")
combo=ttk.Combobox(textvariable=choice)
combo["value"]=("Conor Mcgregor","Jorge Masvidal","Colby Covington","Tony Ferguson","Sean O malley")
combo.grid(row=0,column=1)


Label(text="ประเมินทักษะมวยปล้ำ",font=20,pady=10 ,padx=10).grid(row=1,column=0,sticky=W)
Label(text="ค่าทักษะมวยสากล",font=20,pady=10 ,padx=10).grid(row=2,column=0,sticky=W)
Label(text="ค่าทักษะมวยไทย",font=20,pady=10 ,padx=10).grid(row=3,column=0,sticky=W)
Label(text="ค่าทักษะBJJ",font=20,pady=10 ,padx=10).grid(row=4,column=0,sticky=W)

WrestlingPoint1 = IntVar()
sb1 = Spinbox(from_=1,to=10,textvariable=WrestlingPoint1)
sb1.grid(row=1,column=1)

WrestlingPoint2 = IntVar()
sb2 = Spinbox(from_=1,to=10,textvariable=WrestlingPoint2)
sb2.grid(row=1,column=2)

BoxingPoint1 = IntVar()
sb3 = Spinbox(from_=1,to=10,textvariable=BoxingPoint1)
sb3.grid(row=2,column=1)

BoxingPoint2 = IntVar()
sb4 = Spinbox(from_=1,to=10,textvariable=BoxingPoint2)
sb4.grid(row=2,column=2)

MuayThaiPoint1 = IntVar()
sb5 = Spinbox(from_=1,to=10,textvariable=MuayThaiPoint1)
sb5.grid(row=3,column=1)

MuayThaiPoint2 = IntVar()
sb6 = Spinbox(from_=1,to=10,textvariable=MuayThaiPoint2)
sb6.grid(row=3,column=2)

BJJPoint1 = IntVar()
sb7 = Spinbox(from_=1,to=10,textvariable=BJJPoint1)
sb7.grid(row=4,column=1)

BJJPoint2 = IntVar()
sb8 = Spinbox(from_=1,to=10,textvariable=BJJPoint2)
sb8.grid(row=4,column=2)

Label(text="รวมผลคะแนน", font=20,pady=10 ,padx=10).grid(row=5,column=0,sticky=W)

Label(text="คะแนนนักสู้คนที่ 1 ",font=20,pady=10 ,padx=10).grid(row=6,column=1)
Label(text="คะแนนนักสู้คนที่ 2 ",font=20,pady=10 ,padx=10).grid(row=6,column=2)

#content1=""
#content2=""
txt_input= StringVar(value="0")
txt_input2= StringVar(value="0")

TOTAL1 = Entry(window, font=('impact', 15,'bold'),fg='black',bg='green',width=10,textvariable=txt_input)
TOTAL1.grid(row=5, column=1)
TOTAL2 = Entry(font=('impact', 15,'bold'),fg='black',bg='yellow',width=10,textvariable=txt_input2)
TOTAL2.grid(row=5, column=2)

lbl_1 = Label(text=f"ผลการวิเคราะห์คะแนนพบว่า {choice.get()} เป็น มวยต่อ(Favorite) \n {opponet.get()} เป็นมวยรอง",
                      font=('Arial',13),background='blue',fg='black')

lbl_2 = Label(text=f"ผลการวิเคราะห์คะแนนพบว่า {opponet.get()} เป็น มวยต่อ(Favorite) \n {choice.get()} เป็นมวยรอง", font=('Arial',13),background='green',fg='black')

lbl_3 = Label(text=f"ผลการวิเคราะห์คะแนนพบว่า {choice.get()} สูสีคู่คี่กันกับ {opponet.get()} ", font=('Arial',13),background='grey',fg='black')

 

def TOTALSCORE1():
    #global content1
    content1=WrestlingPoint1.get()+BoxingPoint1.get()+MuayThaiPoint1.get()+BJJPoint1.get()
    txt_input.set(content1)
    
def TOTALSCORE2():
    #global content2
    content2=WrestlingPoint2.get()+BoxingPoint2.get()+MuayThaiPoint2.get()+BJJPoint2.get()
    txt_input2.set(content2)

#going=Label(window)
#going2=Label(window)
#summary=Entry(font=('impact',15,'bold'),fg='black',bg='red',width=10,textvariable=txt_input).grid(row=10, column=0,columnspan=0)

def comparescore():
    #global going
    total1 = WrestlingPoint1.get() + BoxingPoint1.get() + MuayThaiPoint1.get() + BJJPoint1.get()
    total2 = WrestlingPoint2.get() + BoxingPoint2.get() + MuayThaiPoint2.get() + BJJPoint2.get()


def pickfighter():
     
    lbl_4.configure(text=f"{choice.get()} ปะทะ {opponet.get()}",font=('impact',13),background='aqua',fg='black')
    lbl_4.grid(row=9,column=0)
    
    TOTALSCORE1()
    TOTALSCORE2()
    
    total1 = WrestlingPoint1.get() + BoxingPoint1.get() + MuayThaiPoint1.get() + BJJPoint1.get()
    total2 = WrestlingPoint2.get() + BoxingPoint2.get() + MuayThaiPoint2.get() + BJJPoint2.get()
    
    if total1 > total2:
        lbl_1.configure(text=f"ผลการวิเคราะห์คะแนนพบว่า {choice.get()} เป็น มวยต่อ(Favorite) \n {opponet.get()} เป็นมวยรอง",
                      font=('Arial',13),background='blue',fg='black') 
        lbl_1.grid(row=10, column=0, columnspan=2)
    elif total2 > total1:
        lbl_2.configure(text=f"ผลการวิเคราะห์คะแนนพบว่า {opponet.get()} เป็น มวยต่อ(Favorite) \n {choice.get()} เป็นมวยรอง", font=('Arial',13),background='green',fg='black')
        lbl_2.grid(row=10, column=0, columnspan=2)
    elif total1 == total2:
        lbl_3.configure(text=f"ผลการวิเคราะห์คะแนนพบว่า {choice.get()} สูสีคู่คี่กันกับ {opponet.get()} ", font=('Arial',13),background='grey',fg='black')
        lbl_3.grid(row=10, column=0, columnspan=2)
     

def clearcommand():
    lbl_1.destroy()
    lbl_2.destroy()
    lbl_3.destroy()
    lbl_4.destroy()
     
     
    TOTAL1.delete(0, END )                                                                                                           
    TOTAL2.delete(0, END )
    
    WrestlingPoint1 = IntVar(value=0)
    sb1.configure(textvariable=WrestlingPoint1)

    WrestlingPoint2 = IntVar()
    sb2.configure(textvariable=WrestlingPoint2)

    BoxingPoint1 = IntVar()
    sb3.configure(textvariable=BoxingPoint1)

    BoxingPoint2 = IntVar()
    sb4.configure(textvariable=BoxingPoint2)

    MuayThaiPoint1 = IntVar()
    sb5.configure(textvariable=MuayThaiPoint1)

    MuayThaiPoint2 = IntVar()
    sb6.configure(textvariable=MuayThaiPoint2)

    BJJPoint1 = IntVar()
    sb7.configure(textvariable=BJJPoint1)

    BJJPoint2 = IntVar()
    sb8.configure(textvariable=BJJPoint2)

lbl_4 = Label(text=f"{choice.get()} ปะทะ {opponet.get()}",font=('impact',13),background='yellow',fg='black')
    
confirm=Button(text="ยืนยัน",command=pickfighter,font=30,background='blue').grid(row=11,column=0)
clear=Button(text="เคลียร์ข้อมูล",command=clearcommand,font=30,background='red').grid(row=11,column=2)

window.mainloop()
```

Screenshot:

[image]